# Spring MongoDB Embedded document getting null or blank

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

document(grandSubCategory) is embedded by subCategory and subCategory embedded by Category now. here is mongo collection(category). I'm trying to get grandSubCategory by id, but it keep getting null or blank when I request in postman.

```
{
    "_id" : "4",
    "name" : "Machine",
    "ancestors" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "parent" : "null",
    "subCategory" : [
        {
            "_id" : "5",
            "name" : "Living",
            "parent" : "4",
            "grandSubCategory" : [
                {
                    "name" : "AC",
                    "parent" : "5",
                    "spec" : [
                        {
                            "size" : "20X20",
                            "material" : "plastic",
                            "unit" : "CM^x2"
                }]}]}]}
```

this is service

```
@Override
    public GrandSubCategory getGrandCategoryById(String id) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
        return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, GrandSubCategory.class);

@GetMapping("/getGrandCategoryById/{id}")
    public GrandSubCategory getGrandCategoryByName(@PathVariable String id){
        GrandSubCategory category = categoryService.getGrandCategoryById(id);
        return category;
```

Comment: IIRC, there's an issue where for the `_id` in the root of the document, spring data mongodb converts it to `id`. However, for sub-documents, it does NOT do this. It's been raised as a bug (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3351) which cannot be fixed without introducing a breaking change.

Comment: @jeremyt. Hi I just check your link. so I'm still confused that there's no way to get sub-documents?

Comment: yes, but if you use `_id` it will not be transformed by spring into `id`, you'll have to either use `_id` or use one of the Jackson annotations to alias the field.